# How to make page that redirects dynamically based on URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect

Sorry for bad title, I really don't know how to describe this problem. Any suggestion is welcome.
I have to implement this in one large asp.net project (c#):
-  user enters some url in browser, which should be in this form:

```
http://servername/directory/M1234N/2
```

where M1234N and 2 are some example values that can be different based on user needs.
Based on those two values, page should be redirected to another page. Basically, program should extract those two values from URL and based on that calculate where to redirect.
Is this even possible?
Thank you!
PS Sorry for bad post and title, feel free to correct me anytime

Comment: Firstly, where is M1234N and 2 defined that it should give a certain URL? What is the algorithm for creation? Is it static or dynamic?

Comment: assuming it is static url,i think you need url routing!

Comment: I am not sure, task is just to enter the specific url and based on values to redirect. I tried as Christos suggested but it does not work

Answer (score 3):

Yup it is possible. Initially, you have to read these values from the query. In order to do so, you should read the url

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Then you have to split it based on `"/"`.

```
string[] splittedUrl = text.Split('/').ToArray();
```

This way you will get an array, whose last two elements would be that you want:

```
string val1 = splittedUrl[splittedUrl.Length-1];
string val2 = splittedUrl[splittedUrl.Length-2];
```

Now based on the `val1` and `val2` you can find the page you want to redirect the user and you can redirect it as you would do in any other case.

Comment: he is passing the url directly into the browser and i think for your method you will need a extra page on that page load you will do this?or i think  by url routing will be good for direct redirecting

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But it does not work. That part is easy. Problem is how to save this page in VS projekt? If I name it somehow e.g. RedirectPage.aspx when I type in browser: http://localhost/RedirectPage/M1234N/2 I just get an error

Comment: The first thing that you have to define is what are M1234 and 2? How these values are associated with the page you want to show. Then you could make an association between the pages and these values. If you give me a hint about these values and their relation with the pages you want to show, I may find out how you could do this. thanks

Comment: Problem is how to create aspx page in application that can process those two values (that can be anything user wants). Processing is not important, problem is how to get program to process such link like for instance: localhost/RedirectPage/M1234N/2 where RedirectPage.aspx exist in projekt and the other values should be processed when this link is in browser

Answer (score 0):

Use this method.

1. Add a global.asax file to project
2. add this method to global.asax ile

   ```
     void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {

               string para2;

               string para1;

               string CurrentPath = Request.Path.ToLower();

           if (CurrentPath.Contains("http://servername/directory"))
           {

               //Get the two parameters from the url, here i am assuming that directory is static 
               //If not then you can change below two line for getting the passed parameters from url.
               //I think it is easy task just use some string functions         
               para2 = CurrentPath.Substring(CurrentPath.LastIndexOf("/"));
               para1 = CurrentPath.Substring(CurrentPath.IndexOf("directory"), CurrentPath.LastIndexOf("/"));      
               //Now work on these parameters and calculate the redirect page.

               //Replcing the httpcontext with new page
               HttpContext MyContext = HttpContext.Current;
               MyContext.RewritePath("path of your new page according calculations");
           }
       }
   ```

   > In this method the application beginRequest will be called for every request.And you work on the current url.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It seems beginREquest is never called.

Comment: add breakpoint in this method.and make sure you have written this code in global.asax page

Comment: or study about the global.asax file and its methods.It is the proper way of handling the redirecting request in easy way.